# Multiple IN parameters within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I'm using to do a query. This query gathers information from a couple of different tables and a view and compiles the information together.  However, right now I can only get the procedure to take one IN parameter.  I would like to edit it to take two IN parameters so that I may be able to gather more specific information.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gradeReportProcedure(p_courseNo IN varchar2)
IS 
    var_Sname       finalscores.Name%TYPE;
    var_courseNo        finalscores.courseNo%TYPE;
    var_sectionNo       finalscores.secNo%TYPE;
    var_title       course.title%TYPE;
    var_score       finalscores.score%TYPE;
    var_lettergrade     gradeploicy.letterade%TYPE;
    var_Ins_fname       inst.fname%TYPE;
    var_Ins_lname       inst.lname%TYPE;


CURSOR AverageCursor IS

    select distinct finalscores.NAME, finalscores.COURSENO, finalscores.secNo, course.TITLE, round(finalscores.SCORE,2), gradeploicy.LETTERADE, INST.FNAME, INST.LNAME
    from finalscores, gradeploicy, course, INST
    where finalscores.COURSENO = course.COURSENO
    and finalscores.SCORE between gradeploicy.LOWBOUND and gradeploicy.UPPBOUND
    AND INST.INS_NO = course.INS_NO;

begin
    open AverageCursor;

    FETCH AverageCursor
          INTO var_Sname, var_courseNo, var_sectionNo, var_title, var_score, var_lettergrade, var_Ins_fname, var_Ins_lname;


   [Formatting and information that needs to be omitted]


    LOOP

    FETCH AverageCursor
      INTO var_Sname, var_courseNo, var_sectionNo, var_title, var_score, var_lettergrade, var_Ins_fname, var_Ins_lname;
    EXIT WHEN AverageCursor%NOTFOUND;


    dbms_output.put_line(var_Sname||' '||var_score||'       '||var_lettergrade);
    dbms_output.put_line(' ');

END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Err, how about `p_courseNo IN varchar2, p_somethingElse IN <datatype>`?

Comment: When done like this, it will accept the input, however the following result isn't correct.  For instance, say I input 'CS1xx','1' (it's a procedure that gets class information) I'll get all of the information rather than getting just Cs1XX section 1's information.

Comment: Obviously, you'd need to change the query to use your parameters (which you haven't used at all btw)

Comment: @Phil Okay, I'm going to open up to you and tell you that I'm walking on a limb here.  I honestly have not had a lot of experience with stored procedures and the books that I have are not helpful in explaining everything that we can do with them.  

You say I haven't used my parameters.  Can I use p_Variable, and p_variable2 to change my query?  Like this: 
`select....where finalscores.COURSENO = course.COURSENO
    and INST.COURSENO = P_VAR
    and INST.secNo =    P_var2`

Sorry about the edits.  I'm having an unusually hard time getting used to the tags on this site. O.o

Comment: @Phil nvm! I figured it out. Thanks!